# Spock mocking inputStream causes infinite loop

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a code:

```
gridFSFile.inputStream?.bytes
```

When I try to test it this way:

```
given:
def inputStream = Mock(InputStream)
def gridFSDBFile = Mock(GridFSDBFile)
List<Byte> byteList = "test data".bytes
...
then:
1 * gridFSDBFile.getInputStream() >> inputStream
1 * inputStream.getBytes() >> byteList
0 * _
```

The problem is that `inputStream.read(_)` is called infinite number of times. When I remove the `0 * _` - the test hangs until garbage collector dies.

Please advise how can I properly mock the `InputStream` without falling into infinite loops i.e. to be able to test the row above with 2 (or like that) interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following test works:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class Spec extends Specification {

    def 'it works'() {
        given:
        def is = GroovyMock(InputStream)
        def file = Mock(GridFile)
        byte[] bytes = 'test data'.bytes

        when:
        new FileHolder(file: file).read()

        then:
        1 * file.getInputStream() >> is
        1 * is.getBytes() >> bytes
    }

    class FileHolder {
        GridFile file;

        def read() {
            file.getInputStream().getBytes()
        }
    }

    class GridFile {
        InputStream getInputStream() {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Not 100% sure about it but it seems that you need to use `GroovyMock` here since `getBytes` is a method added dynamically by groovy. Have a look [here](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1-rc-3/all_in_one.html#GroovyMocks).