# Spock mocking inputStream causes infinite loop p2

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have problems with mocking `InputStream` in grails 3.1.7 for spock unit-tests.

I asked similar question before [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014523/spock-mocking-inputstream-causes-infinite-loop).

An issue has been resolved but when I added `@CompileStatic` annotation it returned back. My code:

```
@CompileStatic
class MongoImage implements Image {
    GridFSFile gridFSFile
    ...
    byte[] getBytes() {
        ((GridFSDBFile) gridFSFile).inputStream?.bytes
    }
}
```

My test:

```
given:
List<Byte> byteList = "test data".bytes
def inputStream = GroovyMock(InputStream)
def gridFSDBFile = Mock(GridFSDBFile)
def mongoImage = new MongoImage(gridFSDBFile)

when:
List<Byte> result = mongoImage.getBytes()

then:
1 * gridFSDBFile.getInputStream() >> inputStream
1 * inputStream.getBytes() >> byteList
0 * _
```

This test execution falls into infinite invocation of:

```
1 * inputStream.close()
1 * inputStream.read(...)
```

For my previous question it was resolved by replacing `Mock(InputStream)` to `GroovyMock(InputStream)`. But when I applied `@CompileStatic` the problem returned back.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. full classes with imports (where do `GridFSFile` and `Image` come from, for instance?) and also a full test class. Please do not just post snippets without context, the problem could be in the code you do not show.

Comment: I guess spock doesn't work with `@CompileStatic` and `@TypeChecked` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to mock the inputstream?

Can't you just do:

```
given:
byte[] byteList = "test data".bytes
def gridFSDBFile = Mock(GridFSDBFile)
def mongoImage = new MongoImage(gridFSDBFile)

when:
byte[] result = mongoImage.getBytes()

then:
1 * gridFSDBFile.getInputStream() >> new ByteArrayInputStream(byteList)
0 * _
```

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I've faced. When I removed `@CompileStatic` able to mock the class.
So I've added the `@TypeChecked` annotation for the type checking at compile time